# When is the morphism from global section to stalk surjective

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $X$ be a projective scheme over $\mathbb{C}$ and $\mathcal{F}$ a locally free sheaf on $X$ of rank $2$. Take a point $p$ in the support of $\mathcal{F}$. Suppose that there exists at least $3$ linearly independent global sections none of which vanish at this point $p$. Is it then true that the natural morphism from $H^0(\mathcal{F})$ to the stalk $H^0(\mathcal{F}_p)$ is surjective? If not, is there any bound on the number of linearly independent global sections as above which will ensure a positive answer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I do not think this is true. Since the question is local, we may assume $X = \operatorname{Spec}(A)$ is affine and $\mathcal F$ is free on $X$. Thus, $\mathcal F = \mathcal O_X\oplus\mathcal O_X$, the global sections restrict to $H^0(X, \mathcal F) = A\oplus A$, and $\mathcal F_p = A_p\oplus A_p$. The natural map factors through $A\oplus A\to A_p\oplus A_p$, which is certainly not always surjective.

For example, if we start with $X = \mathbb P^1$ and $\mathcal F = \mathcal O(1)\oplus\mathcal O(1)$, then the support is all of $\mathbb P^1$ and there are linearly independent global sections $(x,0),(y,0),(0,x),(0,y)$, where $x,y$ are coordinates. But in an affine chart with coordinate $u$, setting $p = 0$, we end up with the map $k[u]\oplus k[u]\to k[u]_{(u)}\oplus k[u]_{(u)}$ which is not surjective.

Note that by playing this game with higher twists on $\mathbb P^1$, we can get any number of linearly independent global sections, but the local picture will remain unchanged.

Comment: I guess by $k[u]$, you mean the $k$-vector space generated by $u$. But in that case I think $k[u]_{(u)}$ is isomorphic to $k$. Am I getting something wrong?

Comment: Dear @user46578, no, I mean $A = k[u]$ is the affine coordinate ring of say $y\neq 0$ in $\mathbb P^1$. So $u = x/y$ is a coordinate on $\mathbb A^1$. Then the local ring at the origin $p = 0$ in this chart is given by the localization of $A$ at the prime ideal $(u)$.

Comment: But space of global sections of a variety is finite dimensional $k$-vector space which $k[u]$ is not. Isnt this so?

Comment: Yes, that is so. But I am localizing the global sections to an affine chart first, and then localizing again to the stalk. Maybe that gives an even easier argument though: global sections are finite dimensional, but $A_p$ is not. How can the localization then be surjective?

Comment: Dear @user46578, whoops, that is so -- if the variety is projective. I am simply factoring the natural localization map to the stalks through an intermediate localization.

Comment: I am sorry, I meant global section of $\mathcal{F}_p$. I am editing it.

Comment: Dear @user46578, what do you mean by a global section of $\mathcal F_p$? Is $\mathcal F_p$ not the stalk of the sheaf $\mathcal F$ at $p$ as usual?

Comment: Yes it is. I guess I said something redundant. The point that I am still confused about is that the dimension of $\mathcal{F}_p$ is finite (as $k$-vector space) as $p$ is a projective $k$-scheme. In your example $k[u]_{(u)}$ is not finite dimensional. Is this not the stalk of the sheaf that you are taking? Moreover, localization of $\mathcal{F}_p$ is a subring of $k[u]_{(u)}$ which consists of the graded degree $0$-part. I am sorry. Could you please elaborate a little bit more.

Comment: Dear @user46578, there is no guarantee that the stalk is finite dimensional, only that the global sections of a coherent sheaf are. E.g. for the structure sheaf $\mathcal O$ on $X = \mathbb P^1$ we have $\mathcal O(X)\cong k$, but the stalk $\mathcal O_P$ at a closed point $P$ is isom. to $k[u]_{(u)}$. E.g. if $P\in (y\neq 0)\subset \mathbb P^1$ where $x,y$ are coordinates, then the degree zero piece of the localization of $k[x,y][y^{-1}]$ is just $k[x/y]\cong k[u]$. Then we localize $k[u]$ at the maximal ideal corresponding to $P$.

Comment: Thank you very much. Just one more query. Once we localize $k[u]$ by the maximal ideal $(u)$, the degree zero part of this is isomorphic to $k$, which is the stalk. May be I am getting something wrong agian. Could you please help.

Comment: Dear @user46578, maybe have a closer look at Prop II.2.5(b) of Hartshorne. On $\mathbb P^1$ we have $(y\neq 0) = D_+(y) = \operatorname{Spec}(k[x,y][y^{-1}]_0)$ which is $\operatorname{Spec}(k[x/y])$. Thus, we used the degree zero part to localize to an affine neighbourhood $U = \operatorname{Spec}(k[x/y])$ of the the point $P$. Now looking at Prop. II.2.2., we have that the stalk is the localization of $k[x/y]$ at a max ideal. So I broke it up into two steps, instead of applying Prop. II.2.5(a) directly. To use (a), we must take the degree $0$ part of $k[x,y]_{(x)}$ directly.

Comment: Thank you very much for your patience. I finally understand.

Comment: Dear @user46578, you're welcome.